# Drop a migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

HI ,

I have created a model , which adds some fixture and model and test files and i ran the migration ..

After at some point of time i deleted the files leaving the migration file..

SO that table got created in my db..

Now again i want create the model ,fixtures for tat table .. Is it good to create only those files .. Or shall i run script/generate model again which will creates the fixture files by itself.. WIll it cause any conflict ...

Please give suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not couse any conflict, but there is a chance that you didn't name some file correctly.

In my opinion it is better to run

```
rails generate model_name
```

which will create all needed files and then delete migration file that it creates.